# What do HG and NA mean in Geuvadis project RNAseq sample labels?

Tags: rna-sequencing, microarray

I'm looking at RNASeq Data from Geuvadis [website](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/files/E-GEUV-1/analysis_results/) e.g. the file GD660.GeneQuantRPKM.txt.gz.

The samples are labeled by e.g. HG00105.1.M_120209_7 or NA20812.2.M_111216_6

What do HG and NA mean? Are they ethnic backgrounds?

If not, how can I look up the ethnic mapping to the samples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you google `HG00105`, among the first hits is geo accession [GSM649517](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM649517) with the title `HG00105/NA12878`.

Channel1:

```
Characteristics gender: Male
cell line: lymphoblast cell line HG00105
ethnicity: British from England and Scotland, UK (1000 Genomes codes: GBR)
```

Channel2:

```
gender: female
cell line: lymphoblast cell line NA12878
ethnicity: Northwest European American from Utah (HapMap code: CEU)
```

So no, they are not coding for the ethnic background but are part of the unique identifier of the sample.